# React Native --- Cannot find module '@hapi/joi' Require stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

In my React-Native project, I downloaded the react-native-camera and react-native-qrcode-scanner libraries with node to read qr code, but I started getting such an error while running the application.

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '@hapi/joi'
Require stack:

- D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\schema.js
- D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\readConfigFromDisk.js
- D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js
- D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\install\install.js
- D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
- D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:768:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
  at t (D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\schema.js:9:40)
  at Object. (D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\schema.js:28:17)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:971:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:812:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\schema.js',
  'D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\readConfigFromDisk.js',
  'D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\index.js',
  'D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\install\install.js',
  'D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js',
  'D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js',
  'D:\React\LCapp\LCapp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'
  ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

> yarn install

Comment: I tried it but the situation is still the same